# How to determine compression level of bzip2?

Tags: python, bigdata, bzip2

I have a large collection of bzip2-compressed text files. Uncompressed, some of these take up several GB, so I would like to use the compressed version in my scripts instead of having the uncompressed version take up space on disk. The performance impact caused by this is acceptable in this case.

Unfortunately, these files are compressed with varying compression levels, so when iterating over them, eventually I run into an error:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/bz2.py", line 219, in readline
    return self._buffer.readline(size)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_compression.py", line 103, in read
    data = self._decompressor.decompress(rawblock, size)
OSError: Invalid data stream
```

I assume this is because `bz2.open()` takes an argument `compresslevel`, which, once set, is applied to all files in a call like this:

```
import bz2

dataset = ['first-archive.bz2', 'second-archive.bz2']

for file in dataset:
    with bz2.open(file, 'r', compresslevel=9) as f:
        # do stuff to f
```

Hence my question is this: is it possible, either using Python or Unix-tools, to figure out the compression level used when the bzip2-archive was created?

Comment: the compression level isn't the issue here. this level just tells how hard the compressor must look for similar strings/try various approaches to gain size. It's transparent for the decompressor.

Comment: Hint (perhaps the solution, perhaps not) : open your archives in "rb" mode.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! @Jean-FrançoisFabre, this info is much appreciated! glenfant, any pointers on when to use 'rb' and 'rt' with bzip2? Meanwhile, my hunch is that another process messed with the currently processed file and thus broke the strem... I'm still investigating.

Comment: It seems that indeed something messed with the stream, running the script it a second time succeeded. Thanks again for the assistance, though!